# Movie About AI Taking Over

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for a movie about the military (or intelligence agency) creating an AI system that decides to act on its own.  I do not recall the system's primary function.

Near the beginning of the movie, we see the primary operator die in a car crash.  His brother (identical twin?) is sent in, possibly to investigate, and discovers that the AI system decided to kill the brother to protect itself, and did so by changing a stop light so that he would get t-boned.

It would have been between 2000 and 2010, probably pre-2005.  I had thought maybe it was a Jake Gyllenhaal movie, but his IMDB page begs to differ.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*[Eagle Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_Eye)* (2008) is a good possibility.

[image: Eagle Eye Movie Poster]

> Jerry Shaw (Shia LaBeouf) is a Stanford University dropout who learns his identical twin brother Ethan, a first lieutenant in the US Air Force, has been killed. Following the funeral, Jerry is surprised to find $751,000 in his bank account. Later he finds his Chicago apartment filled with weapons, ammonium nitrate, classified DOD documents, and forged passports. He receives a phone call from a woman (Julianne Moore) who warns that the FBI is about to arrest him and he needs to run.

....

> Agent Perez is summoned by Secretary of Defense George Callister (Michael Chiklis) to be read into Ethan's job at the Pentagon. Ethan monitored the DOD's top secret intelligence-gathering supercomputer, the Autonomous Reconnaissance Intelligence Integration Analyst (ARIIA). Callister leaves Perez with Major William Bowman (Anthony Mackie) and ARIIA to investigate Ethan Shaw's death. Simultaneously, Rachel and Jerry learn that the woman on the phone is actually ARIIA, and that she has "activated" them according to the Constitution's authorization to recruit civilians for the national defense.

It has an identical twin killed in a car accident, an A.I. gone haywire, and the time frame fits.

Comment: This is almost definitely it.  Too bad it's not on any streaming services.  Might have to rent it from Amazon.